# Why does opening new zsh terminal print environment vars

Tags: zsh, macos

Each time I open a new terminal in Mac OS, it prints a selection (but not all) of my environment vars. I use zsh shell. e.g

```
HOME=/Users/xxxx
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LESS=-R
LOGNAME=xxxx
LSCOLORS=Gxfxcxdxbxegedabagacad
LS_COLORS='di=1;36:ln=35:so=32:pi=33:ex=31:bd=34;46:cd=34;43:su=30;41:sg=30;46:tw=30;42:ow=30;43'
SHELL=/bin/zsh
SHLVL=3
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.UHkqxMAS4R/Listeners
TERM=xterm-256color
TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=447
TERM_SESSION_ID=8D1EB9B1-1C23-4EAC-BC52-DB90C5D41625
TMPDIR=/var/folders/6g/5p5g9sxn4m94j8cnk4hkx_x80000gn/T/
USER=xxxx
XPC_FLAGS=0x0
XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
ZSH=/Users/xxxx/.oh-my-zsh
_CE_CONDA=''
_CE_M=''
__CFBundleIdentifier=com.apple.Terminal
```

I tried removing zsh and reinstalling and this hasn't fixed it. The same happens when I `source .zshrc`.

Comment: soooo maybe share your `.zshrc`?

Comment: something in your .zshrc (or something run from .zshrc) is printing them.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks "Community Bot" but the correct answer knew exactly what the issue was and presented a concise solution, so I guess the question *did* have enough detail for them.

Comment: I had the same problem after editing my .zprofile with nano. Nano didn't show the linebreak but another editor did. Vote to reopen this question. It is clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, somewhere in one of the files that `zsh` sources on startup, there's a line containing:

```
export
```

Or:

```
export $VAR
```

Instead of

```
export VAR
```

Where `$VAR` is empty.

To find out where that is, you can start zsh as:

```
zsh -lx
```

Comment: You were correct. There was a long `export PATH=...` statement, which line wrapped. Somehow a carriage return had appeared between `export` and `PATH`.